# What are best practises in writing code to avoid problems with proguard during app-release versions?

Tags: android, proguard

Recently, I had encountered problems with release version of my app.

Everything works fine with debug version. My app size reduced to around 3MB from 9MB with the release version. I came to know proguard does optimisations to code and reduces apk size.

I want to know how can I write code to avoid the same problem with future apps that I build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing, To avoid those problem, you have to add proguard rules for the libraries you are using, in the `proguard-rules.pro` file, which you can find in Gradle Scripts.

**proguard-rules :** These are just some statement which will instructs proguard.

We can easily find proguard-rules for nay library on their git page. Once you find the proguard-rules you just need to copy that and paste them into `proguard-rules.pro` file.

**Note:** We **must check** if we need to **add proguard-rules**, if yes then add it to `proguard-rules.pro` file for **all the libraries** we are using, **otherwise we may face crashes.**

It will be better to check the app even after applying proguard rules. Just to make sure that app is not crashing anywhere.